# How can I fix the 'the condition has length >1' error when adding color scale to each table column in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, gt

I'm trying to write code for a table that adds the color scale to each column based on whether that column is in the table. There are 11 possible columns that won't be in each table iteration. I've been trying to use an `IF()` function, but I keep on getting the error "the condition has length >1." What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code right now

```
all_stats <- all_stats <- data.frame("SEASON" = c("2022-23", "2021-22", "2020-21", "2019-20",
                                     "2018-19", "2017-18", "2016-17", "2015-16"),
                        "Cut" = c(1.26,1.31,1.26,1.59,1.39,1.18,2.28,1.00),
                        "Handoff" = c(1.04,1.09,0.77,0.90,0.97,1.05,1.28,0.82),
                        "Isolation" = c(0.97,0.60,0.59,0.92,0.76,0.56,2.04,0.75),
                        "Misc" = c(0.94,0.91,0.88,0.91,0.74,0.92,2.14,0.65),
                        "Off Screens" = c( 1.17,1.08,1.04,0.98,1.08,1.05,2.01,0.82),
                        "PnR Ball Handler" = c(0.88,1.10,1.06,0.81,0.99,0.92,1.89,0.76),
                        "PnR Roll Man" = c(1.26,0.86,0.93,1.36,0.62,1.12,NA,NA))
plays <-c("Cut", "Handoff", "Isolation", "Misc", "Off Screens", "PnR Ball-Handler",
          "PnR Roll Man", "Postup", "Putbacks", "Spotup", "Transition")
t <-  all_stats %>%
    gt() %>%
    tab_header(title = paste0(playerName," Career Outlook")) %>%
    cols_label(SEASON = "Season") %>%
    if(("Cut" %in% plays)){
      data_color(columns = Cut, apply_to = "fill",
                 colors = col_numeric(domain = NULL,
                                      palette = c('#CF124B','#FFFFFF','#2C5F0D')))
```

The Error I am getting is:

```
Error in if (.) ("Cut" %in% plays) else { : the condition has length > 1
```

Comment: Please don't share code in images - it makes it much harder for others to help you. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example - include code inside a code block, and ideally some data using `dput()`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I made some changes so it is easier to see what is going on.

Comment: Can you please add some (either real or similar) data? The object `all_stats` doesn't exist in the example you've provided so we can't run your code.

Comment: I forgot to do that earlier! Sorry, I am learning hot to do this still. I just added some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `any_of()` from {dplyr}:

```r
all_stats %>%
  gt() %>%
  cols_label(SEASON = "Season") %>%
  data_color(columns = any_of("Cut"),
             apply_to = "fill",
             colors = col_numeric(domain = NULL,
                                  palette = c('#CF124B','#FFFFFF','#2C5F0D')))
```

If the column exists, it will be included in the colouring. If it doesn't exist, it will be skipped over without an error.

[image: Table]